# google app engine recipients mailed costs

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app running on the app engine. Now I am not reaching any of the free limits, except for recipients emailed. My question is, can I pay to just increase that 1 limit? I read the information that google provides about pricing but I can not find an answer to my specific question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. But you can use another service to send mail, like Amazon SES. 
I'am a great fan of app engine. Except for the mail service, because it will give you know feedback about mail delivery. See this issue. 
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1800
I added some code to this issue, to use SES.

Answer (score 0):

No, but why would you want that? Even if you enable billing, you still have all the free quotas.